# Unable to open RViz over SSH, running on Jetson Nano JetPack 4.4 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, docker, ros-humble

I am currently working with a [Limo robot](https://github.com/agilexrobotics/limo_ros2). The GitHub repo contains ROS 2 code for the docker container. Connection via ssh vscode to host machine. The difficulty for me to open RViz and to do SLAM operation with ros2 on this robot. But, following instructions led me to errors,and I wonder if it is possible to develop using RViz over SSH on the Limo robot.

rviz2 command shows the next error, can anyone share solutions?

rviz2
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 1
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! The following links can be helpful: [1](https://answers.ros.org/question/172665/rviz-through-ssh/), [2](https://get-help.robotigniteacademy.com/t/how-to-remotely-access-rviz-running-on-linux-nvidia-jetson-from-windows-pc-over-ssh-x-11/17579/6), and [3](https://answers.ros.org/question/285690/unable-to-run-rviz-and-rtabmap-using-ssh/).

Comment: It is better to paste the text from the error, rather than just a screenshot. Images are not text searchable.

Comment: actually the problem is that YDLIDAR is scanning and not oppening rviz, even i waited for a long time.

Comment: Post your solution as an actual answer and not as a comment. Or if the comment `actually the problem is that YDLIDAR is scanning and not oppening rviz, even i waited for a long time.` is additional info to the question, then please [edit] the question and add the info there. A reader should be able to fully understand the issue just from reading the question, without having to trawl through all of the comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done on any ROS 2-based robot.

If you are interacting with the robot over SSH, and therefore attempting to open RViz over SSH, you will find that this either doesn't work at all (because you're attempting to handle graphics over SSH without X11 forwarding) or that it's very slow (because you are using X11 forwarding, which is a slow process).

Instead of doing it this way, you will have much better results if you use a multi-machine setup. Let the robot run whatever robot control code you want, but have GUIs (like RViz) running on your local device. To do this, you can take advantage of ROS 2's ability to auto-discover nodes across networks, if configured using the approach described in the official documentation [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/Basic/About-Discovery.html) and [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Advanced/Improved-Dynamic-Discovery.html): in short, setting both computers to the same `ROS_DOMAIN_ID` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i edited the question and there are issues with Qt platform, could you provide any solutions?

Comment: @huseynhaydarov This appears to be the same problem as the one that I've outlined: `rviz2 qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 1` is saying that it cannot connect to a display. This is either because you are attempting to open the GUI over SSH, or because you're opening it on your machine and don't have the dependencies there. Make sure you have everything installed on your machine and make sure that you're using the `ROS_DOMAIN_ID` approach.

Comment: i changed to DISPLEY:0 and it opens rviz2, but it does not show the environment and i get the following error:                                                                                                             QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-ros'
[INFO] [1692712020.955772776] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[INFO] [1692712020.956027730] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[INFO] [1692712021.066276790] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED